# Running pt-online-schema-change across multiple hosts

Tags: mysql, database, percona

How can you run this?

```
/home/user/percona-toolkit-2.2.18/bin/pt-online-schema-change -uroot -ppass  
--nodrop-old-table D=production,t=inventory --host shard-db-a-[000-127]
--alter "ADD COLUMN TEST int(11) DEFAULT NULL; " --dry-run
```

Obviously `--host` is only allowed to push to one host.

Is there any option through this percona for multiple `hosts/shards`?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that pt-o-s-c only accepts one host per execution.
Untested, but something like this should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq -w 0 127`
do
  pt-online-schema-change -uroot -ppass \
  --no-drop-old-table D=production,t=inventory --host shard-db-a-${i} \
  --alter "ADD COLUMN test INT DEFAULT NULL" --dry-run
done
```